# Изменения данных в таблице способом рандом

Tags: php

Я как то раз спрашивал как выбрать идентификатор рандомным способом, у меня все получилось и мне посоветовали почитать об рандоме [Здесь](http://hudson.su/2010/09/16/mysql-optimizaciya-order-by-rand/). И вот мне теперь нужно изменить данные этим способом, и я решил зайти на тот сайт, и эффект был был таков: *Смотрю в книгу вижу фигу*. Подскажите как переделать это:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET `all_life`=`all_life`+4 WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

На то чтоб, это часть

```
SET `all_life`=`all_life`+4
```

Добавляла жизни с 2 к 5 , Напрмер

```
SET `all_life`=`all_life`+ от 2 до 5
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос должен быть таким:

```
UPDATE startpoke SET all_life = all_life + 2 + ROUND(RAND() * 3) WHERE id_poke = ?
```

То-есть:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET `all_life`=`all_life` + 2 + ROUND(RAND() * 3) WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")
or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Comment: оо=) работает спасибо =)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET `all_life`=`all_life`+rand(2,5) WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Comment: лучше mt_rand(2, 5) ИМХО.

Comment: А разве `RAND()` в MySQL принимает два параметра?

Comment: нет=) я вот только хотел сказать что то не верно =)